# What are the uses for the bindable and callable pattern?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I've seen this little snippet of code floating around before and never really taken the time to wrap my head around what it does.

```
var bind = Function.bind;
var call = Function.call;

var bindable = bind.bind(bind);
var callable = bindable(call);
```

I understand in concept and in practice what `.bind` and `.call` do, but what is the benefit, advantage or practical use of creating the `bindable` and `callbable` functions above?

Below is a contextual example of a use case for bindable.

```
var bound = bindable(db.find, db).apply(null, arguments);
var findable = bindable(db.find, db);
var bound = findable.apply(null, arguments);
var bound = findable(1, 2, 3);
```

What can this pattern be used for?

Comment: callable lets you turn methods into functions. for example, bold=callable("".bold); bold(123); which makes the bold method generic: able to work on non-strings. this can be very handy when using [].map and [].filter to process collections of different stuff. ex: [1,2,3].map(bold) instead of [1,2,3].map(function(a){return String(a).bold(); })

Comment: another of my favorites: getting rid of jQuery. for example, removing all anchors:  _=callable([].slice); rem=callable(document.body.remove); _(document.querySelectorAll("a")).map(rem);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well `callable` is effectively the result of

```
bind.bind(call);
```

The "executive" summary is that the `callable` function lets you take a function designed to operate as a function on some `prototype` object and create a new function that accepts a parameter to be used as the value of `this`.

As an example, consider the `.slice()` method on the Array prototype. It's often used to transform things like a node list or an `arguments` structure into an array.  That's generally done like this:

```
var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

Well the `callable` function lets us create a stand-alone function that'll work similarly:

```
var cslice = callable(Array.prototype.slice);

var args = cslice(arguments, 0);
```

Now, whether this is *useful* or not as a cornerstone of some kind of programming style, I won't say.