# Difference between facade and module pattern

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I was going through this article and i am confused on the diff between `facade` and `module pattern`.

https://carldanley.com/js-facade-pattern/

```
var MyModule = ( function( window, undefined ) {

  // revealing module pattern ftw
  function MyModule() {

    function someMethod() {
      alert( 'some method' );
    }

    function someOtherMethod() {
      alert( 'some other method' );
    }

    // expose publicly available methods
    return {

      // in our normal revealing module pattern, we'd do the following:
      someMethod : someMethod,

      // in the facade pattern, we mask the internals so no one has direct access by doing this:
      someMethod : function() {
        someMethod();
      }

    };

  }

} )( window );
```

In both the ways we are actually calling the same function which is private. What `big deal` does facade provides?.

Comment: Usually, a facade hides the complex implementation of a *different* module, not of your own code. As can be seen in the DOM event listener example.

Comment: That particular page has previously been [shown to be misleading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27011043/1048572). I wouldn't try to learn much from it. In fact, the [facade is a *design* pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), and doesn't have much to do with code structure. One can use the JS "module pattern" to implement a facade.